# Facebook to Salesforce Sales cloud / Service cloud Integration

Tags: marketing-cloud, integration, servicecloud, sales-cloud, facebook

1) First question, can we Integrate FACEBOOK and Sales cloud via API or any app?

2) I have a page fan page in my FACEBOOK account, can I bring them [who liked, subscribed to my page] as LEADS/CONTCACTS to my Sales cloud account?

I am aware of the concept **WEB-to-LEAD**, does this is the ONLY option!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, depending on what actions you would like to take with those leads, remember that some form of consent is needed in order to send them an email, etc. Grabbing everyone who liked your fan page and sending them an email without consent wouldn’t be a good idea, that’s why the **Lead Forms** are in place in both below solutions.

---

For Marketing Cloud integration, you would need to get Advertising Studio enabled in your account to be able to use **Lead Capture in Advertising Studio**.

To connect your Facebook advertising leads with Marketing Cloud Data Extensions in real time, use Advertising Studio’s Lead Capture feature.

Before you use this feature, you must:

-Enable data extensions in your Marketing Cloud account

-Create a Facebook lead advertising form

-Have admin level permissions on the Facebook page associated with the lead advertising form

Source: https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_ads_lead_capture.htm&type=5&sfdcIFrameOrigin=null

---

For Sales Cloud-only integration, you can use **Salesforce Lead Capture**

Automate the flow of customer information directly from Facebook into Sales Cloud for sales teams to manage lead pipeline directly. Leads appears automatically in real time, using a secure connection to Facebook.

Source: https://appexchange.salesforce.com/appxListingDetail?listingId=a0N3A00000DrzmfUAB

Comment: Hi @zuzannamj thanks for the above solution with respect to Marketing cloud... How about if I don't have any Marketing Cloud account..... and I have only purchased Sales cloud.. how would you advise now!

Comment: I updated my anwser

Comment: Hi @zuzannamj , Thank you very much! ... this helped a lot.. I have added tags of sales and service cloud... just out of my curiosity and expanding my full query..... 1) WIll this hold good for **Service cloud** as well? 2) Are there similar app to use with INSTAGRAM/

Comment: Not sure if this would work with Service Cloud, as lead capture is not a service related process.. and nothing that I know of on AppExchange dedicated to Instagram. There might be some 3rd party custom solutions, but those would cost you extra..

Comment: Thanks for all the details and confirmations.

Answer (score 1):

So far I know there is no automation tool which can complete this requirement

> I have a page fan page in my FACEBOOK account, can I bring them [who liked, subscribed to my page] as LEADS/CONTCACTS to my Sales cloud account?

. So, You need to do some development here on Salesforce using apex and use some APIS.

For the integration of Facebook with Salesforce, you can use the following steps.

1) First, authenticate Facebook with Salesforce using customization.

1. [Enable API](https://support.geckoboard.com/hc/en-us/articles/217148797-How-do-I-enable-API-access-in-Salesforce-) in your profile.
2. Create an [App on Facebook](https://developers.facebook.com/).
3. Create the [Facebook Auth Provider](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=sso_provider_facebook.htm&type=5).
4. Create [NamedCredentials](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=named_credentials_about.htm&type=5)

Now Salesforce will handle your authentication automatically.

2) Now you can use the [Facebook API guide](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/) and develop your functionality in apex and do any kind of customization you like on Salesforce.

Web-to-Lead is to generate leads using Forms.